# How to pass xml file to new object in Jmeter

Tags: java, xml, jar, jmeter, performance-testing

I am importing a JPOS jar to jmeter.

using the same jar i am creating the ISO massages.

while invoking the "GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("basic.xml");" getting an error as "Typed variable declaration : Object constructor"

Can someone help me to create object.

below is the Benshel code.

```
import java.io.*;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager;


    //public class BuildISOMessage {

    //  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
            // Create Packager based on XML that contain DE type
            GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("basic.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, the only reason I can think of is JMeter is not being able to locate `basic.xml` file. Consider the following workarounds:

- Copy `basic.xml` file to JMeter's "bin" folder
- Pass full path to `basic.xml` file to GenericPackager constructor like:

  ```
  GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("C:/somefolder/anotherfolder/basic.xml");
  ```

In general you cat surround your code with [try/catch block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) and print the stacktrace into JMeter log file as follows:

```
try {
    //your code here
}
catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Something went wrong", ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

When an error occurs you will be able to see detailed message in *jmeter.log* file.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using Beanshell in JMeter tests.

It looks like it isn't a problem to build an ISO message using Beanshell following steps from [Jimmy's Blog – ISO 8583 Tutorial – Build and Parse ISO Message using JPOS library](http://jimmod.com/blog/2011/07/26/jimmys-blog-iso-8583-tutorial-build-and-parse-iso-message-using-jpos-library/) post:

[image: JMeter Beanshell JPOS]

Comment: Thanks for ans... but issues got resolved it is because of "genericpackager.dtd" file was missing  after placing the same in bin folder or where basic.xml is placed its running fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issues was because of "genericpackager.dtd" not placed at same location where "basic.xml".

once you placed same its running fine